# How to select users who made an order $x days ago

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I need to query a WordPress database with WooCommerce installed to find all users who made an order within the last 5 days. I need to run raw MySql - I don't have the option of using WP or WooCom APIs.

So far I have

```
SELECT wp_users.user_login as "users::username",
       wp_users.user_email as "users::email"
  FROM wp_users
 WHERE (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE(date_format(DATE_SUB(NOW(),
                                                        INTERVAL 5 DAY),
                                               '%d-%m-%Y'),
                                   '%d-%m-%Y')) <
       UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE(date_format((SELECT wp_posts.post_date
                                                 FROM wp_posts
                                                 JOIN wp_postmeta
                                                   ON wp_postmeta.post_id     =
                                                      wp_posts.ID
                                                  AND     wp_postmeta.meta_key =
                                                      '_customer_id'
                                                WHERE wp_posts.post_type     =
                                                      'shop_order'
                                                  AND     wp_postmeta.meta_value =
                                                      wp_users.ID
                                                ORDER BY     wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 1),
                                               '%d-%m-%Y'),
                                   '%d-%m-%Y')));
```

It's returning 0 results, where there should be 2. Obviously something is amiss with my query. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't think that wp_postmeta.meta_value contains the userid - does it??

Comment: No, actually it's '_customer_user ' instead of '_customer_id' - haha that solves it, thanks for your input guys.

Answer (score 0):

`_customer_id` should be `_customer_user`